# Do ice and poison slowdowns affect the rate of inferno?

Tags: clash-royale

Inferno damage rate  (Inferno Tower, Inferno Dragon) increases over time if left uninterrupted.  Does slowdown from ice attacks (Ice Wizard, Ice Golem) or Poison (pre-Oct. 20, 2016 slow removal nerf) affect the rate that inferno damage increases?

Comment: Finally, our Inferno Towers aren't going to be slown down that easily by Poison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, slow effect from Poison, Ice Wizard and Ice Golem slows ramp up time for Inferno Tower and Inferno Dragon damage. The slow effects do not stack, so the greatest slow effect you can get in the game is 35% from Ice Wizard.

Also, the Zap spell will reset the Inferno tower damage.

Resources: [Reddit.com/r/ClashRoyale](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashRoyale/comments/4nsuv1/does_poison_slow_the_inferno_towers_damage_ramp/), [ClashRoyaleWiki](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Ice_Wizard)

EDIT: As of October 20, 2016, the Poison spell no longer slows movement or attack speed of troops or buildings and will only deal damage.

Comment: Just little update to this answer at 20.10. 2016 SuperCell removed slow efect on Poison spell.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, they do.** The Inferno Beam is just something visual; in the deep game-mechanics, these units just attack like any other unit (every 0.4 Seconds) in the game. This proves that the answer is true.

*Just as an in-game example: People sometimes pair up the Ice Wizard with the Giant. I usually defend against the Giant with an Inferno Tower. When the Ice Wizard starts attacking, my Tower reaches its critical Damage point significantly slower than normal.*